# Co-Ordinate Geometry : Please find the mistake

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Om69o.png

I think there is some mistake in my diagram or the work. Please check the link .

The above formula is of Distance Formula(in the link). that is $$\sqrt{(x_2 - x_1)^2 + (y_2 - y_1)^2}$$ but I am getting it as (please see the link for the work) : $$\sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2 + (y_1 - y_2)^2}$$
Please let me know about my mistake .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No mistake, your formula and the class formula are equal because:
 $$y_2-y_1 = (-1)\cdot(y_1-y_2)$$
so
$$(y_2-y_1)^2 = (-1)^2(y_1-y_2)^2=(y_1-y_2)^2$$

Comment: Oh got it. So I was doing nothing wrong, just applied wrong logic in understanding my work. Thanks Thomas.

Comment: The only problem in your logic was the thinking that two formula that are different are not equal.